# ASP.NET session out problem. frequently logout problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a ASP.NET MVC razor application with authentication. I used a custom implementation of AuthorizeAttribute.

When I run it locally, it works fine, but when I upload and run it from the website then it frequently logs out while working without leaving website idle.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If the asp.net session is stored in memory and you recycle the app domain, you will loose all sessions in memory.  If you control the web server, you might research into any reason for recycles: [see](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx).  If you want your sessions to persist across these events you will need to look into other [session state modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)